# Laravel 4 Workbench Undefined offset

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Trying to create a new package following the Official docs.

When I try

```
php artisan workbench myvendor\mypackage --resources
```

I get an Exception

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined offset: 1","file":"\/var\/www\/laravel\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Workbench\/Console\/WorkbenchMakeCommand.php","line":94}}
```

I'm new to Laravel so more than likely doing something wrong.

I have filled in my name and email in the config.

Running Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel will try to split the `vendor/package` string on the `/` so it MUST be a `/` and not a `\`. So your command should be:

```
php artisan workbench myvendor/mypackage --resources
```

Comment: Thanks. I was following the official Laravel docs.
Laravel is well documented but it's quite annoying when the documentation is wrong! lol

Comment: You should point out on [GitHub](http://github.com/laravel/docs) where the problems are. I can't seem to find any reference to creating a package with `vendor\package`.

Comment: Will do. I'n new to this whole "Community" thing :P I'm used to just sitting with the PHP Manual.

Comment: I think they corrected it after I went in to IRC and asked. I'd copied and pasted it so couldn't be me seeing things. Thanks again